# Mongodb $setOnInsert not working with $max and $min

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have the following query that works fine without `$max` and `$min`, however, when `$max` and `$min` are included nothing happens?

```
Summary.update({
  productId: _product._id,
},{
  $addToSet: { 
    attrs: _variant.attrs,
    vars: {
      variantId: _variant._id,
      title: _variant.title,
      imgs: _variant.imgs,
    } 
  },
  $max: { 'price.highest': _price.highest },
  $min: { 'price.lowest': _price.lowest },
  $setOnInsert: self.summary
},{
  upsert: true
},function(err,update){
  ...
});
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query does come with come caveats, so it really only remains to explain what would be going wrong.

First and foremost is that your MongoDB server version must be at least version 2.6.x or greater in order to have the [**`$min`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/min/) and [**`$max`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/max/) update operators available.

Now consider the basic test conditions:

```js
> db.test.update(
    { "a": 1 },
    { 
        "$setOnInsert": { "b": 2 },
        "$min": { "c": 1 }, 
        "$max": { "d": 1 } 
    },
    { "upsert": true }
  )
WriteResult({
    "nMatched" : 0,
    "nUpserted" : 1,
    "nModified" : 0,
    "_id" : ObjectId("559f114dbe78f212535e2f5f")
})
```

On a first execution since there is no data for a matching value of "a" an `upsert` is performed creating the new object in the collection:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("559f114dbe78f212535e2f5f"),
    "a" : 1,
    "d" : 1,
    "c" : 1,
    "b" : 2,
}
```

Now if you change the values of `$min` or `$max` the expected behaviour is to modify those fields where the value falls within the constraints, like so:

```js
> db.test.update(
    { "a": 1 },
    { 
        "$setOnInsert": { "b": 3 }, 
        "$min": { "c": 2 },
        "$max": { "d": 2 }
    },
    { "upsert": true }
  )
  WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
```

Since the value to `$min` is larger than the stored value this field is not changed. However the value to `$max` is larger than the stored value and that is modified. There was a different value in `$setOnInsert`, but this does not affect the data since the operation is not an `upsert` this time:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("559f114dbe78f212535e2f5f"),
    "a" : 1,
    "d" : 2,
    "c" : 1,
    "b" : 2
}
```

If you then issue a statement with either the same values for `$min` and `$max` or that othewise fall out of the contraints of being respectively "lower" or "higher" values then nothing will be updated:

```js
db.test.update(
    { "a": 1 },
    { 
        "$setOnInsert": { "b": 3 },
        "$min": { "c": 2 }, 
        "$max": { "d": 2 } 
    },
    { "upsert": true }
)
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })
```

That is the expected behavior of the operators in this context. Of course if you submit either `$min` or `$max` on a field that does not exist yet, then the field is added to the document with the specified value, just like with `$set` or `$push` or similar.

So either you are subitting values that do not meet the requirements for updating or your supported server and/or driver versions are not capable of handling the operators. These are all the things you need to check to see why you don't think you are getting the expected results.

As a side note, beware that you know what you are expecting with `$addToSet` as well. In a similar way, if the complete object exists already then nothing will be modified. If however you have an object with various keys as you do, then changing any one of those values makes the whole object "unique" and a new member will be added. If you mean to do something else like have only "one" of the keys to contain a unique vallue thene there is other logic you need to apply and cannot simply use `$addToSet` to handle it.

Also, here is a full listing you can run with node and mongoose in addition to the above test conditions. This is tested against MongoDB 3.x and mongoose 4.0.6:

```js
var async = require('async'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var testSchema = new Schema({
  "a": Number,
  "b": Number,
  "c": Number,
  "d": Number
});

var Test = mongoose.model('Test',testSchema,"test");


async.series(
  [
    function(callback) {
      Test.remove({},callback);
    },
    function(callback) {
      Test.findOneAndUpdate(
        { "a": 1 },
        {
          "$setOnInsert": { "b": 2 },
          "$min": { "c": 1 },
          "$max": { "d": 1 }
        },
        { "upsert": true, "new": true },
        callback
      );
    },
    function(callback) {
      Test.findOneAndUpdate(
        { "a": 1 },
        {
          "$setOnInsert": { "b": 3 },
          "$min": { "c": 2 },
          "$max": { "d": 2 }
        },
        { "upsert": true, "new": true },
        callback
      );
    },
    function(callback) {
      Test.findOneAndUpdate(
        { "a": 1 },
        {
          "$setOnInsert": { "b": 3 },
          "$min": { "c": 2 },
          "$max": { "d": 2 }
        },
        { "upsert": true, "new": true },
        callback
      );
    }
  ],
  function(err,results) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log( JSON.stringify( results, undefined, 2 ) );
    process.exit();
  }
);
```